# How to remove a non-existent changelist from a job in Perforce?

Tags: perforce

When opening the job in P4V, the following error occurs:

[image: P4_error]

The job does open but shows no information for the faulty changelist:

[image: JobDescription]

It was not possible to remove the job from this changelist from either the visual client or command line (curated result):

```
> C:\>p4 fix -d -c 735556 POST-45079
> Change 735556 unknown.
> 
> C:\>p4 fixes -j POST-45079
> POST-45079 fixed by change 735556 on 2019/06/07 by ... (closed)
> POST-45079 fixed by change 735415 on 2019/06/05 by ... (closed)
> POST-45079 fixed by change 735366 on 2019/06/10 by ... (closed)
> POST-45079 fixed by change 735355 on 2019/06/05 by ... (closed)
> POST-45079 fixed by change 735334 on 2019/06/04 by ... (closed)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a database inconsistency, so you should consult with Perforce's tech support if you can.  It might indicate a bug in Perforce, or it might indicate a problem with your server (e.g. a problem with the disk that caused a db write to get dropped).

Leaving aside the root cause, if you just need to fix this immediate problem, I think given the inconsistency between the tables you won't be able to do it as an end user and will need an admin to apply a journal patch.  They'd do that by putting this into a text file (call it e.g. `jnl-fix.txt`:

```
@dv@ 1 @db.fix@ @POST-45079@ 735556 0 @status@ @client@ @user@
@dv@ 1 @db.fixrev@ @POST-45079@ 735556 0 @status@ @client@ @user@
```

and then running `p4d -jr -f jnl.fix.txt` in the server root.  That'll delete the relevant fix records.

Comment: Thanks @Samwise. I'll check with my administrator.